# Is This Educational Model of Electron Any Good?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, education

To help me understand electrons better I came up with this educational model. This is not a theory, just an attempt to possibly update current didactic models.

Instead of an electron being a cloud, swirling and creating stationary waves around a nucleus, what about this:

Imagine a pinball thrown into a roulette wheel. A pinball is going to come in with a certain kinetic energy and jump all over the wheel. In the case of electron speed is about 1% of speed of light, actually (1/137 * c).

In a 'classic' roulette wheel, pinball is going eventually to loose energy to friction etc. and its going to settle down in one slot. But if pinball somehow can retain its kinetic energy, it would stay forever in the 'pinball cloud' around the roulette.

In the context of quantum mechanics and electron, there is going to be no loss of energy and electron will retain its initial kinetic energy and keep bouncing around the nucleus (aka. its roulette wheel) forever. Because electron's enormous speed, (1/137 * c), it will look as a cloud.

As well, this 'pinball' like electron cloud, will settle in a different orbitals proportional to its own initial kinetic energy. And over the time, it can receive or emit energy from photons.

Does this educational model explain electron with more consistency than current didactic models?

Comment: IMO, not a good device.  You'd have to specify a number of roulette wheels, one for each orbital, and why should an electron go to one roulette wheel over another?  You'd have to re-construct the entire picture with energy levels corresponding to roulette wheels, but why a roulette wheel?  It's a hand-waving, literary device indicating an idea of chance, not the kind of probability you want.

Comment: In quantum mechanics we have uncertainty and well defined states that show interference. In probabilistic systems we have central limit theorems. You won't find a central limit theorem anywhere in QM and you won't find interference terms anywhere in probability theory. One can create something similar to a delocalized ground state with a random driving force in a classical system and that's where things end for that approach.

Answer (score 2):

Quantum interactions behave in a much more wave-like way than a pinball model would suggest. The interactions are *quantised*, which is where a lot of the particle-like behaviour comes from, but until an interaction depends on the specific position of the electron, it will continue to behave much more like a wavy cloud than a ball.

The pinball will also fail to display any of the wave-like energy behaviours:

1. It does not have a wavelength
2. There is no sense of oscillation permitting resonance
3. The pinball can be stopped and reach zero energy, unlike a bound electron
4. A ball on a roulett wheel will move broadly in a ring-like shape, whereas the inner-most orbital is a cloud centred on the nucleus; the electron *spends some of its time inside the nucleus*, and the nucleus has the highest wavefunction amplitude.

A better picture is of a drum; it has a fundamental frequency at which the drum vibrates with a circularly-symmetric oscillation, which has greatest amplitude at the centre of the drum. Higher order resonance occurs with various shapes of standing waves, which have identifiable patterns and wave numbers (radial and angular).

The pinball model will not, for example, assist in understanding the delocalised electrons on an [aromatic compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromaticity), for which it is vital to understand the wavelike nature of resonance and delocalisation; a model based on a highly localised particle representation is not going to work here.

If you measure the position of an electron in a vacuum, and then leave it alone, and then re-measure it, you discover that the wavefunction spreads out - it behaves like a particle only when forced to interact with a larger system. Otherwise, it behaves more like a wave. In quantum chemistry, the electron density is considered, rather than necessarily individual electrons. In fact the wave-like behaviour becomes more important when considering multiple electrons around an atom; if it were two negatively-charged pinballs and a positively-charged nucleus, then we would expect the two pinballs to sit stationary on opposite sides of the nucleus. Instead, the two electrons take opposite spins and form overlapping clouds centred on the nucleus, and further electrons take up resonance shapes.

Looking at more physical phenomena, the wavelike properties of electrons are more important in understanding diffraction of electrons (matter waves), entanglement, excitation, phonons, Surface Acoustic Waves, spintronics, 1D Electron Gas, quantum tunnelling, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. Very good explanation. I didn't know that "... the electron spends some of its time inside the nucleus", which is amazing! So, in the simplest form, electron is like a wave and when a massive object interacts, than wave shrinks into particle. Maybe, larger system takes some energy out of electron wave and makes the wave to shrink into particle?

Comment: The phrase "The wave shrinks into a particle" has no physical meaning really

Comment: The particle vs wave behaviour is not the electron changing from one to another. They are just analogies we can grasp which describe aspects of the electron's behaviour. When a large system interacts with an electron (e.g. you measure its position) no energy is necessarily given to or taken from the electron, but the interaction does affect the state of the electron. In deterministic interactions the electron has to yield a valid deterministic answer so the wavefunction is said to collapse - really this is not well understood but it is more like a selection. It is not a particle or a wave.

Comment: @COROVICD: Electrons don's spend any time anywhere. An electron is a measurement on a quantum field. Do the numbers on a physicists printout spend time inside a nucleus? No, they don't.